# Filter pandas multi index data frame based on index column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the below Muti index data frame,

```
|  shape  |  colour  |        data        |
|                    |  d1  |  d2  |  d3  |
-------------------------------------------
| circle  |  green   |  2   |  4   |  9   |
| circle  |  red     |  -9  |  3   |  1   |
| square  |  orange  |  5   |  -6  |  2   |
| square  |  yellow  |  9   |  8   |  2   |
```

created with the following,

```
header = [ "shape", "colour", "label", "data" ]  
data = [      
[ "circle",  "green",  "d1", 2  ],
[ "circle",  "green",  "d2", 4  ],
[ "circle",  "green",  "d3", 9  ],
[ "square",  "orange", "d1", 5  ],
[ "square",  "orange", "d2", -6 ],
[ "square",  "orange", "d3", 2  ],
[ "circle",  "red",    "d1", -9 ],
[ "circle",  "red",    "d2", 3  ],
[ "circle",  "red",    "d3", 1  ],
[ "square",  "yellow", "d1", 9  ],
[ "square",  "yellow", "d2", 8  ],
[ "square",  "yellow", "d3", 2  ],
]

raw = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
df = raw.pivot(index=["shape", "colour"], columns=["label"], values=["data"])
```

and I want to filter the data values based on the colour. It is easy with a set value, I can do, `df[(abs(df["data"]) > 2)]` but I do not know/cannot find how to do it when the threshold depends on the colour. With the following filter,

```
filter = {
    "red": {"threshold": 5},
    "green": {"threshold": 5},
    "yellow": {"threshold": 7},
    "orange": {"threshold": 1},
}
```

The desired output would be,

```
|  shape  |  colour  |        data        |
|                    |  d1  |  d2  |  d3  |
-------------------------------------------
| circle  |  green   | Nan  | Nan  |  9   |
| circle  |  red     |  -9  | Nan  | Nan  |
| square  |  orange  |  5   |  -6  |  2   |
| square  |  yellow  |  9   |  8   | Nan  |
```

I tried,

```
df.apply(lambda r: r["data"] if abs(r["data"]) > filter[r.index.get_level_values(1)].get("threshold", 2) else 0)
```

and

```
df[(abs(df["data"]) > filter[df.index.get_level_values(1)].get("threshold", 0))]
```

to no avail.

Comment: You can certainly do the filtering BEFORE the pivot.  The pivot is mostly to make it prettier for human readers, so it should probably be last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `filter` dictionary create `DataFrame` with colours as index. Then reindex the latter with the `df` index's `'colour'` level. Compare `df` to the obtained values (an individual threshold for each row depending on colour):

```
threshold = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(filter, orient='index') 
mask = df.abs() > threshold.reindex(df.index.get_level_values('colour')).values
print(df[mask])
```

Output:

```
              data          
label           d1   d2   d3
shape  colour               
circle green   NaN  NaN  9.0
       red    -9.0  NaN  NaN
square orange  5.0 -6.0  2.0
       yellow  9.0  8.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

From you dataset, we can use a `numpy` method called [`select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) like so :

```py
import numpy as np


filter = {
    "red": {"threshold": 5},
    "green": {"threshold": 5},
    "yellow": {"threshold": 7},
    "orange": {"threshold": 1},
}

condlist = [(raw['colour'] == i) & (raw['data'].abs() > filter[i]['threshold']) for i in filter]
choicelist = [raw['data'] for i in filter]            

raw['vals'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)
```

Output :

```
>>> raw
    shape   colour  label   data    vals
0   circle  green   d1          2   NaN
1   circle  green   d2          4   NaN
2   circle  green   d3          9   9.0
3   square  orange  d1          5   5.0
4   square  orange  d2         -6  -6.0
5   square  orange  d3          2   2.0
6   circle  red     d1         -9  -9.0
7   circle  red     d2          3   NaN
8   circle  red     d3          1   NaN
9   square  yellow  d1          9   9.0
10  square  yellow  d2          8   8.0
11  square  yellow  d3          2   NaN
```

Then we can apply the pivot to the data to get the expected result :

```py
df = raw.pivot(index=["shape", "colour"], columns=["label"], values=["vals"])
```

Output :

```
>>> df
                vals
        label   d1      d2      d3
shape   colour          
circle  green   NaN     NaN     9.0
        red    -9.0     NaN     NaN
square  orange  5.0    -6.0     2.0
        yellow  9.0     8.0     NaN
```